# to create column with classes from numeric column

Tags: r

Objective is to create a new columns from the height column With 3 classes as:

- height<5 is low;
- height>=5 & <=10 is medium and
- height>10 is high.

How do I do that? I tried:

```
estudo[estudo$heigth<5,]$classheigth<-"baixo"
```

but it gave error.

```
"missing values are not allowed in sub scripted assignments of data frames"`
```

Sample data

```
# dput(head(estudo, 10))
estudo <- structure(list(height = c(2, 10, 20, 15, 3, 6.333333333, 7, 6, 3.4, 7)), 
   .Names = "height", row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
estudo$class <- cut(estudo$height, c(0, 5, 10, Inf), 
                    labels = c('low', 'medium', 'high'))
```

**Output is:**

```
      height  class
1   2.000000    low
2  10.000000 medium
3  20.000000   high
4  15.000000   high
5   3.000000    low
6   6.333333 medium
7   7.000000 medium
8   6.000000 medium
9   3.400000    low
10  7.000000 medium
```

**Sample data:**

```
estudo <- structure(list(height = c(2, 10, 20, 15, 3, 6.333333333, 7, 6, 3.4, 7)), 
                    .Names = "height", row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: With the cut at 5, this will put a value of 5 in the low category instead of medium

Comment: @Onyambu use argument `include.lowest` in `cut` to control the behavior.

Comment: @Lerong ..i just pointed that out. Not working on it. Thanks though.

Comment: It works well on the small data frame. In the large data frame this error occurred: behavior $ classheigth <- cut (behavior $ height, c (0, 5, 10, Inf), labels = c ('low', 'medium', 'high' cut.default (behaviour2 $ height, c (0, 5, 10, Inf), labels = c ( "low" 'x' must be numeric Thanks

Comment: It seems `height` in your original dataframe is not numeric. You can verify it using `class(behavior$height)` and maybe `as.numeric(behavior$height)` might help in this case. @Onyambu - I agree and yes Lerong's suggestion seems to partially solve this concern. But I feel that OP needs to re-define the range.

Comment: I used class(behavior$height) and is: class(behaviour$heigth) [1] "logical" alse I used behaviour$heigth<-as.numeric(behaviour$heigth) but the error to be continued. Thanks!

Comment: Please share `dput(head(behavior))` and the exact code you ran on this data so that the error can be reproduced. Point to note here is that `height`'s class is 'logical'.

Comment: Ok. structure(list(Code = structure(c(16L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("10", "12", "15", "20", "3", "30", "35", "4", "5", "50%", "6", "7", "70%", "8", "9", "ad", "al", "ocio"), class = "factor"), Comp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Boca", "deitada", "ocio", "rume"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Code", "Comp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: And. behaviour2<-subset(behavior, Comp=="Boca")
arenum <- sapply(behaviour2$Code, function (x) gsub('[[:digit:]]', '', x) == '')
behaviour2$heigth <- ifelse(arenum, is.numeric(behaviour2$Code), NA)
behaviour2$subTyPA <- ifelse(!arenum, as.character(behaviour2$Code), NA)
behaviour2$classheigth <- cut(behaviour2$height, c(0, 5, 10, Inf), 
                              labels = c('low', 'medium', 'high')) Thanks.

Comment: There are two things which need attention in your implementation. 1) typo - i.e. mismatch in `heigth` & `height` and 2) `Code` is a factor variable so you need to run `behaviour2$height <- ifelse(arenum, as.numeric(as.character(behaviour2$Code)), NA)`.

Answer (score 0):

And if classes are not too many, you can also do:

```
estudo$class[estudo$height < 5] <- "low"
estudo$class[estudo$height >= 5 & estudo$height <= 10] <- "medium"
estudo$class[estudo$height > 10] <- "high"

      height  class
1   2.000000    low
2  10.000000 medium
3  20.000000   high
4  15.000000   high
5   3.000000    low
6   6.333333 medium
7   7.000000 medium
8   6.000000 medium
9   3.400000    low
10  7.000000 medium
```